# Emailing contents of a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

My app generates information from textfields to a uitextview, i was wondering how i could send this information on a email when the user clicks a button.

The mail application should open and it will have the contents of the uitextview in the body of the email.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you struggling with any particular part of the documentation for mfmailcomposeviewcontroller?

Comment: ive read it but im pretty new to all of this so im finding it hard to start, could you point me in the right direction of what i need to use please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it with `MFMailComposeViewController`. Here's the code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[composer setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[composer setMessageBody:@"Email Body" isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];

[composer release];
```

Just replace `@"My Subject"` with your real subject and `@"Email Body"` with your TextView's contents. You can also set  `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` fields and add some attachments via this class.

You can also check if app **can** send an email by using:

```
[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];
```

E.g. if user didn't configure his email accounts, this function will return `NO`.

---

More info about sending emails from your app you can find in [MFMailComposeViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`. You also have to attach `MessageUI` framework to your target.

Comment: but my textviews contents changes depends on what to user inputs into the textfields, so how would i email a value that depends on the users input?

Comment: Replace `@"Email Body"` with `yourTextView.text` where `yourTextView` is your text view instance name.

Comment: thankyou very much! when i place the button i will just need a simple ibaction? with your code in it?